# How to implement GANs by tensorflow estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

In GANs, there are two train operations: one for minimize the generation loss, the other for minimize the discriminator loss.

However, in [tensorflow estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), there is **only one train_op**, so how can I combine the two train operations into one?

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `tf.group` to combine two OPs into one.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group

Comment: Did using `tf,group` solve your problem? If yes, could you please share an example of using it to define a single train_op and loss for a GAN?